# WiFi authentication timing out (Linux Mint / Thinkpad)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, iwlwifi

I woke the laptop up form hibernation, as I have done 1000 times before, but this time no wifi... it appears to be some kind of authentication time out.

I've done a load of research and tried various fixes (rebooting, disabling iwlwifi 11n, restarting network-manager etc) and despite almost identical descriptions of the problem nothing works.

Syslog:

```
wlp: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
device (wlp): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
wlp: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
wlp: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 3/3)
wlp: authentication with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx timed out
wlp: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="XXXXXX" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
device (wlp): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
```

lshw returns:

```
driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-55-generic
```

I've no idea what has changed overnight to cause this and the logs are not very forgiving... Please help!

Answer (score 2):

So I tested the laptop's wifi by connecting to my mobile phone using Mobile Tethering and it worked fine...

I looked at the router settings and, having previous ready something about channel widths, I changed the channel width from 20mhz to 20/40mhz.

Suddenly the wifi is working, which is bizarre considering I didn't change any router settings to trigger this issue.